# Flutter: Firebase get async date

Tags: flutter

When I try to access the database in real time, I get the data but they come later than the container is drawn, ie the container is drawn and only then the data is obtained and as a result the cards are not drawn, what to do

This is the class I use to get data from the database:

```
class GetDateImage {
var subject = new PublishSubject<String>();

PublishSubject<String> _readDate(String childName) {
final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(childName);

DBRef.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  subject.add(dataSnapshot.value.toString());
});

return subject;
}

}
```

But this is the widget in which I call to receive data

```
Widget CardsDashboard(String childDataName) {
var subject = new PublishSubject<String>();
var getImage = new GetDateImage();
List<Widget> trigger = [ ];

subject = getImage._readDate(childDataName);

subject.stream.listen((event) { 
var urls = event.split(',');

trigger = RenderCards().renderCard(urls);
print("1");
});
print("2");

return Container(
height: 500,
child: PageView(
controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0),
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
pageSnapping: true,
  children: trigger
),
);
}
```

Well, the result itself

```
flutter: 2
flutter: 2
flutter: 1
flutter: 1
```

I installed two prints, and the one in which 1 should be executed first but executed second, why? And how to fix it

Comment: Research how to handle futures in flutter. Your current method seems to be a hack to get around the analyzer throwing errors.

Comment: While looking into handling futures, also look at the FutureBuilder widget, which is what you need to use for this use case.

Comment: Thank you, it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used StreamBuilder everything worked, thank you very match